# R Timevis Package How to add groups, Add line, Invert x axis, etc

Tags: r

From R, I'm trying to put together an interactive Gantt chart, to track the processes performed, later I'll add in my PowerBI report/dashboard. From what I researched, the Timevis package is very good and meets my needs, but I'm not managing to develop it the way I need it.

I put the examples in the photo, but I will also put them here in topics:

- How to add groups with start and end date and time?
- How to change the colors of the groups?
- How to change the x axis (of time) upwards?
- How to make the axes (time and groups) bold?
- How to add a line, every time a group meets ("collide between them")? How do I count them later?
- Why does a graph have a line from the time, and another does not (I prefer without)?

I am uploading the data manually for testing, but the data will come from an Oracle base later when I get it working.

Script 1, with groups:

```
library(timevis)

timevis(data = data.frame(
  content = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60),
  start = c("2020-06-03 23:50:00", "2020-06-03 23:30:00", "2020-06-03 20:00:00", "2020-06-03 19:00:00", "2020-06-03 18:00:00", "2020-06-03 18:30:00"),
  #end = c("2020-06-04 00:00:00", "2020-06-03 23:45:00", "2020-06-03 23:00:00", "2020-06-03 20:10:00", "2020-06-03 19:00:00", "2020-06-03 19:00:00"))
  group = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)),
  groups = data.frame(id = 1:6, content = c("Power BI","Analysis Services","Oracle","ODI","Microsoft Flow","PowerShell"))
)
```

Script 2, without groups:

```
library(timevis)

timevis(data = data.frame(
  content = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60),
  start = c("2020-06-03 23:50:00", "2020-06-03 23:30:00", "2020-06-03 20:00:00", "2020-06-03 19:00:00", "2020-06-03 18:00:00", "2020-06-03 18:30:00"),
  end = c("2020-06-04 00:00:00", "2020-06-03 23:45:00", "2020-06-03 23:00:00", "2020-06-03 20:10:00", "2020-06-03 19:00:00", "2020-06-03 19:00:00"))
  #group = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)),
  #groups = data.frame(id = 1:6, content = c("Power BI","Analysis Services","Oracle","ODI","Microsoft Flow","PowerShell"))
)
```

Example from script 1:

[image: Example 1]

Example from script 2:

[image: Example 2]

Comment: Multipart questions used to be deprecated. In the last year there seems to have been a relaxation of standards and policies, but I suspect that is still expected. I think you should narrow the question. Since it appears the output is html, you might get an answer that would be easily generalized to the remaining questions. Use [edit] and read [ask]. If you address this question promptly it may prevent closure, but if you let it sit unaddressed, then I predict others will also vote to close as too broad.

Comment: @IRTFM I'm sorry, but I don't know what I can edit, because I've got all theses questions for the same script/package from R. The questions I narrow from topics, so anyone can understand my point. That's why I even got two scripts, because I didn't manage to get it done by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I was really new at `timevis` and `shiny` package, I didn't know how to use both, but I'm now able to acomplish almost everything I wanted from my question.

So here how I did:

```
  # Create a data as dataframe that will appear on chart
  dataLog <- data.frame(
    title = paste("Processo:", c("test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5", "test6"), sep = " "),
    content = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60),
    start = c("2020-06-03 23:50:00", "2020-06-03 23:30:00", "2020-06-03 20:00:00", "2020-06-03 19:00:00", "2020-06-03 18:00:00", "2020-06-03 18:30:00"),
    end = c("2020-06-04 00:00:00", "2020-06-03 23:45:00", "2020-06-03 23:00:00", "2020-06-03 20:10:00", "2020-06-03 19:00:00", "2020-06-03 19:00:00"),
    style = c("border-color: black; font-size: 15px; Background: #492378; Color: white; font-weight: normal", 
              "border-color: black; font-size: 15px; Background: #5E2C99; Color: white; font-weight: normal", 
              "border-color: black; font-size: 15px; Background: #7638C2; Color: white; font-weight: normal;", 
              "border-color: black; font-size: 15px; Background: #8C43E6; Color: white; font-weight: normal;", 
              NA,
              "border-color: black; font-size: 15px; Background: #b578ff; Color: white; font-weight: normal;"),
    group = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))

  # Create data groups
  dataLogGroups <- data.frame(
    id = 1:6, 
    content = c("G1", "G2", "G3", "G4", "G5", "G6"),
    style = "font-weight: bold")

  # Plot timevis chart
  timevis(dataLog,dataLogGroups,showZoom = TRUE,options = list(orientation = 'top'))
```